# Replacing the first occurence of an element in a list

Tags: list, functional-programming, scheme, lisp, sisc

I am writing a function `replaceFirst(X Y L)` which replaces only the first occurrence of X with Y in the list L.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
(define replaceFirst( lambda (X Y L)
    (cond
        ( (null? L)             '() )
        ( (equal? (car L) X)    (set! Y (cdr L)) )
        ( #t                    (replaceFirst X Y (cdr L)) )
    )
))
```

which gives an error of `In procedure setter: Wrong type argument in position 1: #<procedure car (_)>`

**EDIT**

I have come up with a solution:

Firstly, if `X` is the first element, instead of using `set!` (which I am unfamiliar with), I `cons` `Y` to the list excluding `X`.

Otherwise, I `cons` the first element of the list with the function called recursively on the rest of the list.

```
(define replaceFirst( lambda (X Y L)
    (cond
        ( (null? L)             '() )
        ( (equal? (car L) X)    (cons Y (cdr L)) )
        ( #t                    (cons (car L) (replaceFirst X Y (cdr L))) )
    )
))
```

Answer (score 0):

In you clause:

```
( (equal? (car L) X)    (set! Y (cdr L)) )
```

What does the function actually return? And if Y is supposed to be the replacement for X, once you know that **(car L)** is equal to **X**, what would setting the value of the variable Y to be the rest of the list do for you?

Your update is fine, but do note that it returns a *new* list like L, but in which the first occurrence of X has been replaced by Y.  It's not the same list.  That's probably fine, but the use of **set!** in your first attempt suggests that maybe you wanted to modify the list that was passed in as input.

Comment: It doesn't matter that it's a new list. Looking back on my first solution I see how poor it was! I am now attempting to write a function that replaces the LAST occurrence of X with Y in L, which is far more difficult. Any hints on where to get started would be much appreciated.

Comment: @KOB one easy solution would just be `(define (replace-last x y lst) (reverse (replace-first x y (reverse lst))))`.